# Problem with codepoints/integer in XQuery

Tags: xquery

So im trying to execute this simple function:

```
declare function local:decodeBase64() as element(){
  <root-element>
    {    
      let $codepointsString := "77 97 110"
      let $codepoints := fn:replace( $codepointsString,' ',', ')
      let $x := fn:codepoints-to-string(xs:integer($codepoints))
      return
      $x
    }
  </root-element>
};
```

but i'm getting a error that i think it's because of xs:integer

however i can execute this code with the integer hardcoded

```
let $x := codepoints-to-string((77, 97, 110))
```

I noticed that i can run the code if i declare $codepoints as xs:integer* but i dont't know get a codePoint inside an element and use as xs:integer* to call codepoints-to-string function.

error:

```
http://www.w3.org/2005/xqt-errors}FORG0001: "77 97 110": invalid value for cast/constructor: {http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema}integer: error: decimal: Invalid decimal value: unexpected char '32'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original string needs to be split to multiple codepoint strings. The resulting strings can then be converted to integers:

```
let $codepointsString := "77 97 110"
let $codepoints := (
  for $string in fn:tokenize($codepointsString, " ")
  return xs:integer($string)
)
return fn:codepoints-to-string($codepoints)
```

Comment: I tend to use the bang operator here: `let $codepoints := tokenize($codepointsString, " ") ! xs:integer(.)`